# Pass array values to checkbox

Tags: arrays, laravel, checkbox, multidimensional-array

I have this code

```
@foreach($files['files'] as $file)
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="{{$file}}"></td>
<td>{{file['id']</td>
<td>{{file['name']</td>
<td>{{file['type']</td>
<td>{{file['modified']</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

`$file` contains all the details of 1 file like name, id, modified date, etc.
Can I pass them to checkbox? What I want to happen: when user clicks checkbox, all details of file will contain checkbox. If I concatenate them, I will have a problem in grouping them. The code above inputs Array as string. I want to pass `$file` - all details of 1 file, to checkbox. So when user checks checkbox, will give an array of files with their details.

If I put them out of foreach, it will only have one checkbox. I'm developing a system and I was hoping if someone could help me out. I'm stuck on this problem.

Pls help.

UPDATE:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'evaluate','check_list'=>true, 'method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'check_list')) }}
            @foreach($files['folders'] as $file)
                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" ></td>
                <td>
                    <a href={{url("/home/".$file['file_name'])}}>
                      {{ $file['file_name'] }}
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="center">{{ $file['file_type'] }}</td>
                  <td class="center">{{ $file['file_modified'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $file['file_size'] }}</td>
                  <td class="center">{{ $file['location'] }}</td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="check_list[location]" value="{{$file['location']}}">{{ $file['location'] }}
                  <input type="hidden" name="check_list[file_type]" value="{{$file['file_type']}}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="check_list[file_id]" value="{{$file['file_id']}}">
                  <input type="hidden" name="check_list[file_name]" value="{{$file['file_name']}}">

              </tr>
              @endforeach

            @foreach($files['files'] as $file)
                <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>

               <td>{{ $file['file_name'] }}</td>
                <td class="center">{{ $file['file_type'] }}</td>
                <td class="center">{{ $file['file_modified'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $file['file_size'] }}</td>
                <td class="center">{{ $file['location'] }}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="check_list[location]" value="{{$file['location']}}">{{ $file['location'] }}
                <input type="hidden" name="check_list[file_type]" value="{{$file['file_type']}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="check_list[file_id]" value="{{$file['file_id']}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="check_list[file_name]" value="{{$file['file_name']}}">

               </tr>
              @endforeach
              {{Form::hidden('action')}}
              {{ Form::close()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this doesn't answer your question please update it with a more specific purpose. However in reality all you need is the id of the file as a reference in your check-box then resolve that to you r file in your controller or wherever you handle your post requests.

In your view:

```
@foreach($files as $file)
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{$file->id}}" value="selected"> // or 1 or true
@endforeach
```

In your controller:

```
public function postFile()
{
    $files = File::all() // change according to your model or repository    
    $selectedFiles = [];

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (Input::get($file->id) == "selected")
        {
            $selectedFiles[] = $file;
        }
    }

    // do what you want with the selected files example to show you the array
    foreach($selectedFiles as $selectedFile){
        $selectedFile['was_selected']   =   "Yes";
    }  
}
```

Comment: The you're not doing it right :) Can you please paste here what you've done so I can review it? Maybe edit your question with the new code? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I can see the controller code please? and if possible your File model?